# THREE.JS : Can't rotate camera

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera, rotation

I need my camera to look behind (the x=0,z=0 are in the middle of the pong table)
how can i do it? ( i tried to change everything on camera.lookAt)
[camera look front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2ydV.jpg)

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.id=1;
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, w / h, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.lookAt(0,0,0);
    camera.position.set(0, 3.75, -5);
```

Comment: Can't you just rotate the camera by 180° around the Y-axis? So `camera.rotation.y = Math.PI * 0.5;`.

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer.
i managed to suceed with a new camera instead of rotating.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the order of your operations. When you initialize a new camera, its position is automatically `(0, 0, 0)` and when you do `.lookAt(0, 0, 0)` it probably doesn't know what to do because you're telling it to look at the same point where it already is!

Just do `.lookAt()` after setting position:

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, w / h, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 3.75, -5); // Change position FIRST
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0); // Then tell it to look at origin
```